# Is there a way to throw generics in dart

Tags: dart, oop, generics, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to make a generic function to handle exceptions to reduce code duplications.

the function is like this:

```
Future<T> exceptionHandler<T, E extends Exception>({
  required ValueGetter<Future<T>> tryBlock,
}) async {
  try {
    return await tryBlock();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is E) {
      rethrow;
    }

    throw E( // Error: E isn't a function
      error: e.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

> I have created custom exceptions, one of them is called
> `AuthException`.

This function is intended to be used as follows:

Instead of doing this:

```
Future<bool> signUp({
    required covariant UserModel user,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      // try block code goes here
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is AuthException) {
        rethrow;
      }

      throw AuthException(
        error: e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
Future<bool> signUp({
    required covariant UserModel user,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    return await exceptionHandler<bool, AuthException>(
      tryBlock: () async {
        // try block goes here
      },
    );
  }
```

The `AuthException` is defined like this:

```
class AuthException implements Exception {
  final String error;

  const AuthException({
    required this.error,
  });
}
```

The problem is that I can't throw `E` from the `exceptionHandler` function because `E` is a type and not an object. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly construct an instance of a generic type argument.  Dart does not consider constructors and `static` methods to be part of the class's interface, so the restriction of `E extends Exception` does not guarantee that `E` has an unnamed constructor that takes a named argument `error`.

You instead can have your generic function take a *callback* that constructs the type you want:

```dart
Future<T> exceptionHandler<T, E extends Exception>({
  required ValueGetter<Future<T>> tryBlock,
  required E Function({required String error}) makeException,
}) async {
  try {
    return await tryBlock();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is E) {
      rethrow;
    }

    throw makeException(error: e.toString());
  }
}
```

and then usage would be:

```dart
Future<bool> signUp({
  required covariant UserModel user,
  required String password,
}) async {
  return await exceptionHandler(
    tryBlock: () async {
      // try block goes here
    },
    makeException: AuthException.new,
  );
}
```

I'll also note that your `catch` block will catch *everything*, including `Error`s, [which is usually frowned upon](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses), and it loses the stack trace, which will make failures harder to debug.  I'd restrict the `catch` clause to `Exception`s and use [`Error.throwWithStackTrace`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Error/throwWithStackTrace.html):

```dart
Future<T> exceptionHandler<T, E extends Exception>({
  required ValueGetter<Future<T>> tryBlock,
  required E Function({required String error}) makeException,
}) async {
  try {
    return await tryBlock();
  } on Exception catch (e, stackTrace) {
    if (e is E) {
      rethrow;
    }

    Error.throwWithStackTrace(
      makeException(error: e.toString()),
      stackTrace,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer, I really appreciate it.